# Difference between macro and preprocessor

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

From what I understand , `#define blah 8` is a macro . While , `#` is the pre-processor directive .

Can we say #include,#if,#ifdef,etc. are also macros ,  or are they called something else ? Or is it that macro is just a term used for #define statements only?

*Please correct me if I am wrong.*

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Lines that start with `#` are *preprocessing directives*.  They are directives that tell the preprocessor to do something.

`#include`, `#if`, `#ifdef`, `#ifndef`, `#else`, `#elif`, `#endif`, `#define`, `#undef`, `#line`, `#error`, and `#pragma` are all preprocessing directives.  (A line containing only `#` is also a preprocessing directive, but it has no effect.)

`#define blah 8` is a preprocessing directive, it is not a macro.  `blah` is a macro.  This `#define` preprocessing directive defines the macro named `blah` as an object-like macro replaced by the token `8`.

Answer (score 4):

`#include`, `#if`, etc. are features of the preprocessor.

```
#define blah 8
```

Is a preprocessor directive and declares a new macro named *blah*.

- Macros are the result of a `#define` statement.
- The preprocessor is a feature of C.

Answer (score 4):

Preporcessor: the program that does the preprocessing (file inclusion, macro expansion, conditional compilation).

Macro: a word defined by the `#define` preprocessor directive that evaluates to some other expression.

Preprocessor directive: a special #-keyword, recognized by the preprocessor.

Answer (score 2):

**preprocessor** modifies the source file before handing it over the compiler.

Consider **preprocessor** as a program that runs before compiler.

**Preprocessor directives** are like **commands** to the **preprocessor program**.Some common preprocessor directives in C are

1. `#include <header name>` - Instructs the preprocessor to paste the text of the given file to the current file.
2. `#if <value>` - Checks whether the value is true if so it will include the code until `#endif`
3. `#define` - Useful for defining a constant and creating a **macro**

**macros** are name for some fragment of code.So wherever the name is used it get **replaced** by the fragment of code by the **preprocessor program**.

**eg:**

`#define BUFFER_SIZE 100`
In your code wherever you use BUFFER_SIZE it gets replaced by 100
`int a=BUFFER_SIZE;`
a becomes 100 here

There are also many predefined macros in C for example `__DATE__`,`__TIME__` etc.