# What is the difference between macro and preprocessor directives in C++

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between macro and preprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11958171/difference-between-macro-and-preprocessor)

I have a question about macro and preprocessor directives in C++, what is the difference between them? seems like they are more or less the same? I tried to look up on the internet, but still can not understand it, can anyone help?

Comment: A macro is a textual symbol replacement definition. `#define` is the preprocessor directive use to define a macro.

Answer (score 12):

A preprocessor directive is any of the language features that starts with a `#`, e.g. `#if`, `#pragma`, `#include`.  They're completely processed by the preprocessor as a separate stage, before the proper compiler kicks in.

A macro is anything defined by a `#define`; it's just one particular kind of preprocessor directive.

Answer (score 9):

A macro is a subset of preprocessor directives:

```
#define X
```

This is a macro **and** a preprocessor directive.

```
#pragma once
```

This is just a preprocessor directive.

Macros begin with `#define` and define elements that will be expanded at preprocessing time.

Comment: To be more precise: the `#define` preprocessor directive allows you to create a macro, so in something like `#define X 1234`, `#define` is a preprocessor directive, `X` is a macro, and `1234` is a macro replacement list.