# How to change value defined constants in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, c-preprocessor

I've declared constant as  follows:

```
#define OPENIN_DIR_PATH_FORMAT_STRING L"%@"
```

Now how should I change the value for OPENIN_DIR_PATH_FORMAT_STRING here with %@

Answer (score 2):

`#define` is not making constant it's the macro definition. If you want to change this macro you might do #undef and #define it again. But I strongly discourage you from messing around with macros :)

See [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11958171/difference-between-macro-and-preprocessor) for more details

Comment: In following example how to use value of str in OPENIN_DIR_PATH_FORMAT_STRING  programmatically. 

 e.g.

     NSString *str = @“/path/dir”;

    #define OPENIN_DIR_PATH_FORMAT_STRING L"str" ;

Comment: You cannot use *value* of something in macro. Macros are processed (replaced) before compilation.

Comment: So what is substitute for Define in objective C?

Comment: NSString *const MyConst = @"Constant string". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538996/constants-in-objective-c